# SEO: show all content to Google for infinite scrolling

Tags: seo, google, search-engines

I have a search results page that paginates content loading through `infinite scrolling`.
Now Google recommends [not putting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27323/rel-next-rel-prev-in-infinite-scroll) `rel=next` in this scenario.

Does it make sense to show Google everything when indexed? Is it right?

Comment: Do you really want google to index your search results page? If it can get to all the other content on the site by other means, what exactly would be the point?

Comment: The search page was a metaphor. Lets say, browsing images

Comment: If images then create an image sitemap and submit it to Google and Bing

Answer (score 3):

Google's pretty smart at avoiding infinite loops of links such as calendars on websites. I'm sure they have limits on how much of a page to index if it continues to load and scroll downward. You may opt to go the way twitter and others have setup their sites where users must click a button to load more results. They also don't like indexing search results pages. You're better off building up sitemaps to the content your search results page is linking to then submit those sitemaps to Google.