# For SEO, are pre-rendered previous and next pages required for a single page application site with infinite scroll?

Tags: seo, googlebot, single-page-application

In this [article](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/02/infinite-scroll-search-friendly.html) It is mentioned that

> Chunk your infinite-scroll page content into
>   component pages that can be accessed when JavaScript is disabled.

and

> Add rel="next" and rel="prev" in head section.

My application is highly dependent on spa framework so is there any other way to index infinte scroll for SPA applications or do I have to make custom pre-rendered paginated pages for SEO?

Comment: See also: [How do you implement Rel=next & rel=prev in infinite scroll for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27323/rel-next-rel-prev-in-infinite-scroll)

Comment: Infinite scroll isn't crawled beyond the first page by Googlebot, but pagination isn't great for SEO either.   Infinite scroll doesn't hurt SEO as long as you also have other navigation as well that deep links to your content.

Comment: The page doesn't have any other link to futher content as content is only added after scrolling so there is no other option then paginated pages.

Comment: I'd suggest adding another option instead of pagination such as links to related content and a navigation menu.

Comment: I already added breadcrumb schema but list SEO is still needed. Suppose if my page has 100 items out of which only 20 items are shown at once. how should i get rest 80 crawled?

Answer (score 1):

> My application is highly dependent on spa framework so is there any other way to index infinite scroll for SPA applications

Steven states:

"Infinite scroll doesn't hurt SEO as long as you also have other navigation as well as deep links to your content"

But take note of the last part....  you also have other navigation as well as deep links.

It means you want to make sure there is a reason for people to want to stay on the page and read it.

However, the nice thing about segmenting pages instead of trying to fit hundreds of paragraphs on a single page is that users can find what they want quickly and they won't have to wait for all text to load and they won't have to constantly scroll to find the paragraph they want.

If you don't want to use previous and next, then you should look into categorizing your paragraphs and having one web page per category. If that doesn't condense it enough, then introduce subcategories. Make all the categories as links so that people can use them to find the page they need.

Comment: Your suggestion is good for blogs and text based pages. My application is curation based platform so won't be able to segment further. check page here (https://www.cybrhome.com/topic/career)